# Delete a pointer after the arithmetics

Tags: c++

```
int main() {
  int* i = new int(1);
  i++;
  *i=1;
  delete i;
}
```

Here is my logic:

I increment I by 1, and then assign a value to it. Then I delete the I, so I free the memory location while leaking the original memory. Where is my problem?

I also tried different versions. Every time, as long as I do the arithmetics and delete the pointer, my program crashes.

Comment: u cant free the memory that isn't allocated by u through new, i guess that cause a segmentfault?

Comment: Ho...that's right. So, Let's say, the incremented pointer which is not signed by new is a free-store location. I sign the value, but the location belongs to computer. In this way, I don't need to handle the deletion of it, but I should go back to the original one and delete the original one

Comment: @JiehongJiang: Assigning the value is already so wrong ("Undefined Behavior") that you cannot reliably predict what happens next. You have no idea what you accidentally overwrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your program shows is several cases of undefined behaviour:

1. You write to memory that hasn't been allocated (`*i = 1`)
2. You free something that you didn't allocate, effectively `delete i + 1`.

You MUST call `delete` on exactly the same pointer-value that you got back from `new` - nothing else. Assuming the rest of your code was valid, it would be fine to do `int *j = i;` after `int *i = new int(1);`, and then `delete j;`. [For example `int *i = new int[2];` would then make your `i++; *i=1;` valid code]

Comment: Even `int* i = new int; ++i; --i; *i  = 1; delete i;` would be valid. But that's a really special case for one-after.

Answer (score 1):

Who allocates is who deallocates. So you should not be able to delete something you did not new by yourself. Furthermore, `i++;*i=1;` is UB since you may access a restricted memory area or read-only memory...

The code made no sense . I think You have XY problem. If you could post your original problem there will be more chance to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to have a short understanding how the heap memory management works. in particular implementation of it, when you allocate an object you receive a pointer to the start of the memory available to you to work with. However, the 'really' allocated memory starts a bit 'earlier'. This means the allocated block is a bit more than you have requested to allocate. The start of the block is the address you have received minus some offset. Thus, when you pass the incremented pointer to the `delete` it tries to find the internal information at the left side of it. And because your address is now incremented this search fails what results in a crash. That's in short.

Comment: This is one particular implementation of the free store ("heap"). There are others, which can fail in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take it step by step:

```
int* i = new int(1);  // 1. Allocate a memory.
i++;                  // 2. Increment a pointer. The pointer now points to
                      //    another location.
*i=1;                 // 3. Dereference a pointer which points to unknown
                      //    memory. This could cause segmentation fault.
delete i;             // 4. Delete the unknown memory which is undefined 
                      //    behavior.
```

<s>In short: If you don't own a piece of memory you can't do arithmetic with it neither delete it!</s>

Comment: Ownership is not tied to arithmetic! You don't own string literals, but you can do arithmetic on pointers to them. Deletion means giving up ownership, and therefore your second statement is correct.

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo. Probably should be "you can't do arithmetic with it".

Comment: No, both adjectives are fine, but the statement is just wrong. Practically speaking, `const char* p = "Example"; ++p;` is arithmetic on a pointer to memory you don't own. The result is that `p` points to `'x'` and `std::cout << p;` would print "xample".

Comment: As you say, arithmetic on a pointer to memory is fine, but not with the memory itself. You can't do `++(*p)`.

Comment: That too isn't tied to ownership: `char c = '1'; char* pc = &c; ++(*pc);` - no ownership since the pointer is to stack-allocated memory but arithmetic on the memory itself is fine. Arithmetic on string literals is illegal because they're `const`, which is independent from ownership.

Comment: Next time I'll try to be more precise. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101158/discussion-between-lukas-bednarik-and-msalters).

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```
    i++;
```

This line doesn't increment the value `i` points to, but the pointer itself by the number of bytes an `int` has (4 on 32-bit platform).
You meant to do this:

```
    (*i)++;
```

Comment: Oh, you're right... I see... Sorry, didn't read carefully enough and didn't expect a programmer to intentionally do this kind of thing.